# javascript - How to just add text to a form input

Tags: javascript, forms

I already have a full-fledged form in javascript. All I need is a simple `label` Lol.

It is using prior code, but hopefully this snipet will help to see what's happening:

```
export default class NewEvent extends FormStep {

    get inputs() {
        return [{
            name: 'department',
            label: 'Department / Specific Ministry'
        }, {
            name: 'title'
        }, {
            name: 'description',
            type: 'textarea'
        }, {
            name: 'checkboxApproved',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: 'This copy is approved and is to be used as written.'
        }, {
            name: 'checkboxDetails',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: 'These are the details! Please help me write a catchy description.'
        }, {
            name: 'location'
        }, {
            name: 'contactName',
            label: 'Event Contact Name'
        }, {
            name: 'contactEmail',
            label: 'Event Contact Email (required)'
        }, {
            name: 'contactPhone',
            label: 'Event Contact Phone (optional)'
        }, {
            name: 'eventURL'
        }, {
            name: 'isNewHRock',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: 'This event is a new event we\'ve never done at HRock.'
        }, {
            name: 'hasOccurred',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: 'We\'ve had this event before, but it is not on a recurring schedule.'
        }, {
            name: 'needsRegistration',
            type: 'checkbox',
            label: 'We need to set up registration for this event.'
        }, <EventPrice key = 'eventPrice' /> , <EventClassInfo key = 'eventClassInfo' /> , <EventDateTimeInfo key = 'eventDateTimeInfo' /> ]
    }
}
```

Anyways, all these items show up as a form. AS they should. But I'd like to simply add a label in between the check boxes. I've created the following [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/778552/screenshot.png) of what I'd like to add.

[image]

However, whenever I add `text` in there so far, it breaks the code, or it shows up in a `textfield`...

Help?

Answer (score 1):

This is an object of "inputs".  What ever function is parsing this object is creating all inputs with it, which is why you get a textbox.  I don't think this is the correct place in the code to do this.

Comment: Ok so is there no method for adding an external label to a form like this?

Comment: If even outside of the get inputs () {...} is there a way to add render, or something like that?

Comment: maybe under the eventurl object add `{
            name: eventQuestion',
            label: 'add the text here'
        },`
And then use css to remove the textbox borders and such